# after removing NAs and empty ("") values, still empty values

Tags: r

I am working on a data frame. I removed NAs in a certain column by using:
`df  <- df[-c(which(is.na(df$column))),]`

Further I removed empty values in this column by using:
`df <- df[df$column != "", ]`

Both commands worked fine.
However I still have three empty values left. I wondered if maybe the value is space, but `df <- df[df$column != "\\s+",]` does not delete those values. Does anyone have an idea what might be the value in these empty columns?

EDIT: Example DF

```
dput(df)
structure(list(feature = c("Sorge", "Planung", "genervt", "Liebe", 
"Neugier", "überreagieren", "Blockade", "Registrieren", "Wärme", 
"Barriere", "Wärme", "Glück", "müde", "Neugier", "Selbsthass", 
"anstrengend", "Leidenschaft", "Selbstzufriedenheit", "Selbstzfriedenheit", 
"Turteltaube", "vermeiden", "Ruhe", "Enttäuschung", "bildlich", 
"Entspannung", "Bescheidenheit", "Überraschung", "ungeduldig", 
"verstecken", "Planung", " ", " Angst", " Zukunft", " verwundert", 
" Berührung"), word = c("Vul", "Neif", "Wumeizauch", "Häugnung", 
"Wupforau", "Bismirbiel", "Enkmitas", "Mege", "Weforshank", "Plüpp", 
"Skibt", "Namistell", "Zimerhubst", "Struk", "Mölauzegt", "Bingsemöl", 
"Iberletsch", "Troff", "Odef", "Faube", "Wunicher", "Bisknirgo", 
"Ferandsor", "Zwelde", "Herklögen", "Preier", "Muschürdur", "Ismiprämpf", 
"Glühm", "Rugliebast", "Muschürdur", "Vul", "Neif", "Wumeizauch", 
"Häugnung"), code = c("emo", "neu", "neu", "emo", "neu", "neu", 
"neu", "neu", "emo", "emo", "emo", "emo", "neu", "emo", "emo", 
"emo", "emo", "emo", "emo", "emo", "neu", "neu", "emo", "neu", 
"neu", "neu", "neu", "neu", "emo", "neu", "neu", "emo", "neu", 
"neu", "emo"), trials_fp.thisIndex = c(0L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 2L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 0L, 
1L, 10L, 11L), condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Control", 
"Imagery"), class = "factor"), fpt_rt = c(35.666, 50.282, 42.298, 
63.651, 44.298, 48.083, 59.149, 38.318, 29.734, 69.368, 46.867, 
43.374, 34.367, 42.766, 36.517, 45.999, 34.138, 32.934, 40.366, 
64.555, 44.933, 76.487, 66.467, 48.583, 34.918, 39.918, 37.388, 
42.915, 44.482, 35.151, 37.388, 35.666, 50.282, 42.298, 63.651
)), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000263bedd1ef0>)
```

The column I was talking about is "feature". Rowname 31 is one of the values causing problems.

Answer: df[df$feature != " ", ]

Thank you the dput command made me find out!!!

Comment: You *can* provide an example df: just `dput()` (some of) the df that contains the remaining problem values...

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @Limey, could you post the result of `dput(df)`? If your data are confidential you can subset your dataframe in order to keep only the minimal amount of information.

Comment: For removing the NA's `df  <- df[!is.na(df$column),]` should be enough. Did you check the type of the column with `str` to be character? Did you check the `length` of the empty entries?

Comment: `df <- df[column != "", ]` does not make sense. If `column` is a column of `df`, you should instead have `df <- df[df$column != "", ]`, especially since you have previously subset the data by dropping NA values.

Comment: @VitaminB16 my fault, I did it in R, just did it wrong putting it down here.

Comment: Value 31 in column `feature` is not a missing or an empty character. It's a blank (`" "`, not `""`). So, you just have to run your command once more, this time removing the blanks: `df <- df[df$column != " ", ]`.
Also, you have leading blanks in `" Angst"` and follwing values. You might want to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

`df  <- df[-c(which(is.na(df$column))),]` removes entire *rows* from your data.frame. Maybe what you intended, but I'm putting it here to be clear.

`df <- df[column != "\\s+",]` only works if there is an additional variable named `column`. In your code, `column` does *not* refer to the column in the data.frame.

`column != "\\s+"` does *not* perform regular expression matching. `\\s+` is a regular expression that, AFAIK, matches whitespace (or just string). To use regular expressions in R, use e.g.

```
grepl("\\s+", column)
```

which will return `TRUE` where the pattern matches. In your case, negate it. I.e.:

```
df[!grepl("\\s+", df$column), ]
```

Comment: You suggestion to use `df[!grepl("\\s+", df$column), ]` would have negative consequences, as there are valid cells that contain a space next to other characters. If you remove all lines that contain a space, you lose data.

Comment: True dat. It should have been `"^\\s+$"` to ensure only empty strings were matched. But when I posted this answer, the data wasn't shown.